reading text file in vba comes out empty
I am trying to make a VBA code in word which sends post requests to an server. The post requests work but the problem is that they are empty. I have text files in the folder but it somehow still does not work. I would appreciate every answer.
Code:
Sub AutoOpen()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strSourceFolder As String
    Dim strDestinationFolder As String
    Dim strText As String
    
  
    strSourceFolder = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\myfolder\" 

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
  
    If objFSO.FolderExists(strSourceFolder) Then
        
        
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSourceFolder)
        
       
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
           
            If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "txt" Then
                
                strText = ReadTextFile(objFile.Path)
                
                SendPostRequest strText
            End If
        Next objFile
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder couldnt be found"
    End If
    
   
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    
End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(ByVal filePath As String) As String
   
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strText As String
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
    If objFSO.FileExists(filePath) Then
       
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath, 1) ' 1 für Lesen
        strText = objFile.ReadAll
        objFile.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "txt data couldnt be found " & filePath
    End If
    
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    
    ReadTextFile = strText
End Function

Sub SendPostRequest(ByVal postData As String)
    
    Dim objHTTP As Object
    Dim URL As String
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "https://urlrandom.com/"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    objHTTP.send "data=" & strText
    
   
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub


I tried checking if maybe the folder or the txt file could'nt be found but they are getting found.

strText is not defined in SendPostRequest so it is blank - you need to learn about "Scope" of variables
Edit - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility

In Sub SendPostRequest change objHTTP.send "data=" & strText
to objHTTP.send "data=" & postData
